# JPA Query function gives error

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data-jpa

In my code I have written a JPA Query function for this I am passing a Set ids as parameter.

```
List<InvoiceBillData> findByInvoiceBillDataIdIn(Set<Long> failedInvBillDataIds);
```

My requirement is that I need a List of objects of given ids which is a primary key. But when I run it, JPA's auto generated query throws the error. Currently, Set failedInvBillDataIds has 2 ids, so JPA generated below query. But, it adds extra parentheses.

```
Error Code: 907
Call: SELECT inv_bill_data_id, account_id, billing_profile_id, CURRENCY, current_total, total_due, due_date, bill_id, previous_total, total_taxes FROM INVOICE_BILL_DATA WHERE (inv_bill_data_id IN ((?,?)))
        bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=InvoiceBillData sql="SELECT inv_bill_data_id, account_id, billing_profile_id, CURRENCY, current_total, total_due, due_date, bill_id, previous_total, total_taxes FROM INVOICE_BILL_DATA WHERE (inv_bill_data_id IN (?))")] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
```

How do I need to pass Collection as parameter? Is there any problem with my Query function?

Comment: Please show the entire query in the question. Please also supplement the question with the following information: JPA version used(1.0 or 2.x ?), JPA provider used (hibernate, eclipselink ..?) and it's version, Oracle database version.

Comment: I am using JPA provider org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:2.6.4 and Oracle Database 12C and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa for Spring Boot version (1.4.1.RELEASE). I have just written function, List<InvoiceBillData> findByInvoiceBillDataIdIn(Set<Long> failedInvBillDataIds);  in my JpaRepository where InvoiceBillData is my Entity Class and InvoiceBillDataId is the primary key. As per JPA documentation I have written this query function as I wanted to pass Collection of primary key as  a parameter and wanted List of my Enity Class in return. But, JPA is generating wrong query.